# Powershell: Using [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile in the script

Tags: powershell

I am using [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile in the script to create zip archive, which allows me to use/change path / name formatting for the files in archive.
This is a sample:

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem" 
$compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Fastest
$zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open(c:\temp\archive.zip, 'update')
$files = (Get-ChildItem c:\folder | where-object {$_.Attributes -ne 'Directory'} 
$files| ForEach-Object {[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($zip, $_.FullName,($_.Name),$compressionLevel)}
$zip.Dispose()
```

It works fine, but it's listing all the files in PowerShell execution screen, which I do not like.
So I am getting this for every file being added to archive:

```
Archive          : System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive
CompressedLength : 
FullName         : file1.txt
LastWriteTime    : 11/16/2022 11:55:43 AM -05:00
Length           : 
Name             : file1.txt
```

Is there a way to avoid printing all that info during execution?

Thanks!

searched everywhere, but couldn't find a solution

########
UPDATE :
########

Here is how I am using try/catch, when compressing the files

method #1:

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem" 
$compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Fastest
$zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open(c:\temp\archive.zip, 'update')
$files = (Get-ChildItem c:\folder | where-object {$_.Attributes -ne 'Directory'} 

ForEach ($file in $files){
try {
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($zip, $_.FullName,($_.Name),$compressionLevel)
} catch { # cannot access file
Write-Warning  "Could not archive $($_.FullName). `n $($_.Exception.Message)"  
$Error_Message = $_.Exception.Message
write-warning $Error_Message
write-output "$(get-date) :ERROR Something went Wrong.  ErrorMessage : $Error_Message  " | out-file err_log.txt -Append -Force; 

}Finally{
$zip.Dispose()
}
}
```

I am getting the error message, which is pointing to a file in $Error_Message.

$Error_Message:
**Exception calling "CreateEntryFromFile" with "4" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 'c:\folder\process.log' because it is being used by another process."**

method #2:

Same with "compress-archive" method:

```
try {
Compress-Archive -Path (Get-ChildItem c:\folder | where-object {$_.Attributes -ne 'Directory'}).FullName -DestinationPath 'c:\temp\archive.zip'
} catch { # cannot access file
Write-Warning  "Could not archive $($_.FullName). `n $($_.Exception.Message)"  
$Error_Message = $_.Exception.Message
write-warning $Error_Message
write-output "$(get-date) :ERROR Something went Wrong.  ErrorMessage : $Error_Message  " | out-file err_log.txt -Append -Force; 
} finally{ 
}
```

I do see the error on the screen - **"The process cannot access the file 'c:\folder\process.log' because it is being used by another process." , but $Error_Message is below:**

$Error_Message:
**Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Stream was not readable."**

Not sure how to make compress-archive method to work and grab proper error message.

Thanks -

Comment: [New-ZipEntry.md#example-4-archive-all-files-in-a-specified-location](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression/blob/main/docs/en-US/New-ZipEntry.md#example-4-archive-all-files-in-a-specified-location) might simplify your task

Comment: What is the "proper error message?" Please copy and paste (as text) into the question the output that this code produces. Then, describe what you want to appear.

Comment: Hi Lit, when I am using compress-archive, in case of the file access failure, I am getting $_.Exception.Message as Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Stream was not readable.".  I want to see the path to the file it cannot access.  For comparison, when I am using method #1, I am getting $_.Exception.Message value as below "Exception calling "CreateEntryFromFile" with "4" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 'c:\folder\process.log' because it is being used by another process."  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the CreateEntryFromFile() to `Out-Null`.

Will the `Compress-Archive` command do what is needed?

There should not be and LEFT PARENTHESIS before `Get-ChildItem`.

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem" 
$compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Fastest
$zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open((Join-Path -Path $Env:TEMP -ChildPath 'archive.zip'), 'update')
$files = Get-ChildItem 'c:\src' | Where-Object {$_.Attributes -ne 'Directory'} 
$files |
    ForEach-Object {
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($zip, $_.FullName,($_.Name),$compressionLevel)
    } |
    Out-Null
$zip.Dispose()
```

**Update:**

Catching exceptions. You have to decide what to do if the archive entry creation failed.

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem" 
$compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Fastest
$zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open((Join-Path -Path $Env:TEMP -ChildPath 'archive.zip'), 'update')
$files = Get-ChildItem 'c:\src' | Where-Object {$_.Attributes -ne 'Directory'} 
$files |
    ForEach-Object {
        $ThisFile = $_
        try {
            [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($zip, $_.FullName,($_.Name),$compressionLevel) 2>$null
        } catch {
            Write-Warning -Message "Failed to add $($ThisFile.FullName) to archive."
        }
    } |
    Out-Null
$zip.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have figured it out by myself ... "out-null" - did the trick. As about left parenthesis - yeah it was a copy/paste error. The compress-archive does the same, but using let me to change the structure of the folders inside archive file (if needed). Thanks again!

Comment: also, what I noticed, in case something goes wrong during archiving it deletes the archive file. Let's say the file cannot be archived as "it is being used by another process". This is known limitation when using compressing using powershell native methods. If I use "system.io.compression.filesystem" it does not delete the existing file (if I use -update), but compress-archive deletes the archive when using -update.

Comment: one more thing, when getting error accessing the file in compress-archive. Not getting a proper info in $_.Exception.Message. The actual error is:    The process cannot access the file 'C:\temp\file1.log' because it is being used by another process.
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\temp\file1.log:String) [Write-Error], IOException,   However, the $_.Exception.Message is "Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Stream was not readable.". When using "system.io.compression.filesystem" method, it passes  "The process cannot access the file.... " to $_.Exception.Message

Comment: any idea how to fix it? thx -

Comment: Are you asking how to force the file to go into the archive even if it is open by another process? Please add some try/catch inside the `ForEach` to see if the archiving fails.

Comment: no, #1 - I want to catch an error to variable from "compress-archive", when it cannot add the file to archive, $_.Exception.Message is not catching a file name in the error. However, if I use another "method" [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile  - I am getting all I need when using try/catch.  #2 - How force compress-archive or "[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile " to skip the file it cannot add to archive and CONTINUE without exiting the command. Is it try/catch? Could you please share an example? Thanks everyone for your time

Comment: @Norman, please update the question with your current code using try/catch.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I have updated my question with the code samples. thx!

Comment: Hello @lit,
  Did you have a chance to have a look at my code? Thanks! -

Comment: just an update: I figured out that I have to use try/catch inside foreach block, where every file is being enumerated. Previously, I used "try {" outside of foreach block, so in case of a single file access failure it never went back to foreach block and next command was $zip. Dispose() - as a result it stopped adding files to archive and exit. I was thinking that it is how  "System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" is working - but it was me..LOL  @lit - thanks again!

Comment: @Norman, it seems like you might be saying that this is the correct answer. If so, please select the check mark to indicate that to others.